# convert a simple javascript arary to a list of objects

Tags: javascript

So i'm trying to do something pretty simple.

I have an array that looks like this

```
l = [0.5, 4.5, 7.5]
```

I want to convert it to the following array of objects

```
obj = [
  {value: 0.5, width:2},
  {value: 4.5, width:2},
  {value: 7.5, width:2}
]
```

I seem to keep tripping up on this. Any help would be much appreciated. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this?

```
const numbers = [ 0.5, 4.5, 7.5 ];
const objects = numbers.map( n => ({ value: n, width: 2 });
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to first make an object with the `value` field containing the number on the array, and then assign the width in that same object. This can be done with a for loop.

```
numbers = [0.5, 4.5, 7.5]
obj = []

for (number in numbers) {
   obj.push({value: number, width:2} )
}
```